# Sharepoint 2010 ldap exception FaultException`1

Tags: sharepoint-2010, ldap

i've followed the instruction on the following link:
[Configuring Forms Based Authentication in SharePoint 2010](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2009/11/05/configuring-forms-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

when user logged in: if the username and the password is wrong a message is appear to notify the user to try again

but when the username and the password is right an exception is thrown:

```
    [FaultException`1: Unexpected exception occurred, please contact administrator to resolve this issue.]
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannel.ReadResponse(Message response) +1161205
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannel.Issue(RequestSecurityToken rst, RequestSecurityTokenResponse& rstr) +73
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannel.Issue(RequestSecurityToken rst) +36
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurityContext.SecurityTokenForContext(Uri context, Boolean bearerToken, SecurityToken onBehalfOf, SecurityToken actAs, SecurityToken delegateTo) +26618417
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurityContext.SecurityTokenForFormsAuthentication(Uri context, String membershipProviderName, String roleProviderName, String username, String password, Boolean isPersistent) +26623308
   Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.Pages.FormsSignInPage.GetSecurityToken(Login formsSignInControl) +210
   Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.Pages.FormsSignInPage.AuthenticateEventHandler(Object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs formAuthenticateEvent) +123
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AttemptLogin() +152
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +124
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +70
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +29
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2981
```

Comment: This question would be better suited for http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found the solution, it was because an error in the role provider in web.config , the CN value was wrong